# Accessing boolean from a different class in C#

Tags: c#, class, if-statement, unity-game-engine, boolean

I have one collision script in which I set a boolean to true or false

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class IsTriggerLockCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool CameraLock = false;

    public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) {
        CameraLock = true;
        Debug.Log ("Im inside"); 

    }

        public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
        CameraLock = false;
        Debug.Log ("I exited");
    }


}
```

I want to access this boolean from my camera script, I tried this

```
if (CameraLock == true) {
            Debug.Log ("Im locked");
        }
```

However, I get an error saying that CameraLock doesn't exist in the current context. The boolean is public so I'm very confused.

---

EDIT: I feel like I didn't give good enough info so I'll start by posting the whole camera script and then clarifying.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

    public class CameraFollowLockY : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform target;
        public float damping = 1;
        public float lookAheadFactor = 3;
        public float lookAheadReturnSpeed = 0.5f;
        public float lookAheadMoveThreshold = 0.1f;

        private float m_OffsetZ;
        private Vector3 m_LastTargetPosition;
        private Vector3 m_CurrentVelocity;
        private Vector3 m_LookAheadPos;

        private void Start()
        {
            m_LastTargetPosition = target.position;
            m_OffsetZ = (transform.position - target.position).z;
            transform.parent = null;
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            float xMoveDelta = (target.position - m_LastTargetPosition).x;

            bool updateLookAheadTarget = Mathf.Abs(xMoveDelta) > lookAheadMoveThreshold;

            if (updateLookAheadTarget)
            {
                m_LookAheadPos = lookAheadFactor*Vector3.right*Mathf.Sign(xMoveDelta);
            }
            else
            {
                m_LookAheadPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(m_LookAheadPos, Vector3.zero, Time.deltaTime*lookAheadReturnSpeed);
            }

            Vector3 aheadTargetPos = target.position + m_LookAheadPos + Vector3.forward*m_OffsetZ;
            Vector3 newPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, aheadTargetPos, ref m_CurrentVelocity, damping);

            transform.position = newPos;
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, transform.position.z);

            m_LastTargetPosition = target.position;


        if (CameraLock == true) {
            Debug.Log ("Im locked");
        }
}
```

The `IsTriggerLockCamera` is a script I used for an invisible collider in Unity. My camera is focused on the player at all times, but I want it to stop moving when the player is close to reaching the edge of the map, so he can notice that the map is ending. The original plan was, that the collider would send out information when player enters it and then instead of `Debug.Log ("Im Locked");` would be some code that would lock the camera in place. I don't know if this solution is very elegant and I'd like to apologize for not clarifying everything properly beforehand, but I started coding probably 2 months ago (I did only Rails websites) and I got into C# game development about a week ago so I'm still missing the terminology required to properly describe the problems I encounter. So far, no suggestion has worked. The closest working suggestion was OnoSendai's suggestion, but apparently it's not allowed to create MonoBehaviour using "new".

---

Edit2: Making the boolean static didn't work at first, but then I realized that I had to make some changes in my camera script as well, so it works now, but Philip said that it's a bad advice - I personally have no idea why, I assume that it's something like using !important in CSS, you just use it as a last resort because it makes the code not that flexible - so I'm still open to ideas.

Comment: Well yes, it's public - but you need to access it with respect to a particular instance of `IsTriggerLockCamera`, e.g. `if (triggerLockCamera.CameraLock)` where `triggerLockCamera` would be a variable of type `IsTriggerLockCamera`. Do you *have* such a variable? Are you ever creating an instance of the class?

Comment: Searching for slightly modified title (variable instead of "boolean") https://www.bing.com/search?q=Accessing+variable+from+a+different+class+in+C%23 gives plenty of results - please make sure to check them out and clarify which approaches you've tried and how they did not work for your case.

Comment: show the code of the camera script. An instance of IsTriggerLockCamera  should be injected into it via the constructor of the camera.

Comment: where do you put the first script? In a GameObject?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try a full reference to the `CameraLock` property based on the object instance - as in

```
    var objRef = new IsTriggerLockCamera(); // Just an example of object reference - 
                                            // You may already have one
                                            // on your code.

    if (objRef.CameraLock) {
        Debug.Log ("Im locked");
    }
```

That happens because `CameraLock` is marked as `public`, but not as `static` - it only exists on a instantiated object.

Comment: `new IsTriggerLockCamera()` is very bad recommendation for beginner. While your post technically is correct it is really hard to consider it good suggestion.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's the name the OP gave to his class. While I do agree that there are better naming conventions, I considered the name refactoring to be out of the scope of a proper answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was not talking about naming - `new` is the problematic recommendation from my point of view. It is unlikely that readers would actually try to understand what you said if copy-paste ready sample is present. I'm quite certain that newing up camera will do no good for OP.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Oh, my bad! I see your point, I do agree with you.

Comment: *Edited the original post*

Answer (score 1):

If your camera needs access to the IsTriggerLockCamera then dependency injection is good way to make it clear :

```
class Camera{
    private readonly IsTriggerLockCamera _locker;
    public Camera(IsTriggerLockCamera locker){
       if (locker== null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("locker");
       }
       _locker = locker;
    }
    public void whatevermethod(){
        if (_locker.CameraLock){
           ...
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. Likely not going to help OP as I don't think you can easily fit in to Unity3d script.

Comment: *Edited the original post*

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable you want to access from other scripts, static as well as public.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class IsTriggerLockCamera : MonoBehaviour {
public static bool CameraLock = false;

public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) {
    CameraLock = true;
    Debug.Log ("Im inside"); 

}

    public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
    CameraLock = false;
    Debug.Log ("I exited");
}
```

}

Then you can access `CameraLock` :

```
if (CameraLock == true) {
        Debug.Log ("Im locked");
    }
```

Comment: That means that there can be only one instance of the IsTriggerLockCamera. Bad advice.

Comment: But Unity doesn't make multiple instances of classes if used as scripts.

Comment: Then it is still bad advice because you would be relying on that fact. The code is not reusable. static is to be used wisely.

Comment: *Edited the original post*

Comment: You may look at this post for more info on Static Class wrt Unity3d : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/357564/static-classes.html

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest some approach,

1. Make CameraLock variable as protected.
2. Create a new class and make IsTriggerLockCamera class as base class.
3. consume the CameraLock variable and work on it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

C# has a function called { get; set } that you can use with a variable

This program is an example

Static Type

```
public static class AYO
{
    public static string Variable1 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    
    public void LOL()
    {
        string foo;
        AYO.Variable1 = "Variable is now set";
        foo = AYO.Variable1;
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
    
}
```

Non Static

```
public class AYO
{
    public string Variable1 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    AYO ayo = new AYO();
    public void LOL()
    {
        string foo;
        ayo.Variable1 = "Variable is now set";
        foo = ayo.Variable1;
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
    
}
```